# Using Ramdas 'propSatisfies' Method with variable Object key name

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have an Array of Objects like this:

```
    array = [{
                name: "Object A",
                ratio: {
                    up: 1,
                    mid: 2,
                    down: 1
                }
            },
            {
                name: "Object B",
                ratio: {
                    up: 3,
                    mid: 1,
                    down: 2
                }
            }];
```

And a function like this:

```
getGteLevelPerRatio = (list, keysTrue, level) => {...};
// "level" is of type number and can be 1,2 or 3
// "keysTrue" is an array of type String and can be any element of the power set of ["up", "mid", "down"], eg. ["up"] or ["mid", "down"]
```

With this function i'd like to get every object where at least one property of "ratio" equals one element of "keysTrue", and if they equal the value of the property should be equal or +1 to "level".

---

Example:

keysTrue = ["up", "mid"]

level = 2

returns Object A and Object B, because Object A's ratio.mid === 2, Object B's ratio.up === 3 which is equal to level + 1.

---

If i read the Ramda docs correctly this should be possible with the Ramda 'propSatisfied' Method (see: [Ramda docs - propSatisfied](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#propSatisfies)) , but i don't know how to use the predicate with variable Values.

Here's my rather inefficient Version without Ramda:

```
getGteLevelPerRatio = (list, keysTrue, level) => {
        arrayFiltered = [];
            array.forEach(entry => {
            keysTrue.forEach(keysTrueEntry => {
                for (key in entry.ratio) {
                    if (keysTrueEntry === key) {
                        if (level <= entry.ratio[key]) || level <= entry.ratio[key]) + 1) {
                          arrayFiltered.push(entry);                                
                          console.log(entry.name + " " + key + ": " + entry.ratio[key]);
                        }
                    }
                }
             return arrayFiltered;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Muff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following should do what you want:

```
const getGteLevelPerRatio = (list, keysTrue, level) => {
  const gteKeysFns = R.map(R.propSatisfies(R.gte(R.__, level)), keysTrue);
  return R.filter(R.propSatisfies(R.anyPass(gteKeysFns), 'ratio'), list);
};
```

The first line maps over the `keysTrue` list, creating a list of functions that will return `true` for each key if it is greater than or equal to the given `level` (n.b. we use the `R.__` placeholder here to partially apply `R.gte`'s second argument with `level`).

The second line filters the given list of objects to only those whose `ratio` property satisfies any of the functions in the `gteKeysFns` list.

Comment: Wow - thanks! I think i quite did not yet fully understand the way ramda and/ or the propSatisfies function works. How can you just pass it one argument in line 1 and two arguments in line 2? In the docs it says that propSatisfies takes 3 Arguments - Is this due to currying?

Comment: Exactly. All functions in Ramda are automatically curried, so `propSatisfies` is partially applied in this instance. This effectively means the first call of `propSatisfies` results in a function that expects 2 further arguments (the key and a ratio object) and the second call results in one that is expecting just one further argument (each object that is an element of `array`).

Comment: This is very neat! I like the way of solution-thinking this way of programming offers.